# Total number of comments of an author posts

Tags: wordpress

I wanna display total number of comments that other users submitted for all posts of an author! for example something like this :

```
get_author_posts_total_number_of_comments($author->ID);
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_author_posts_total_number_of_comments($authorID)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(comment_count) AS total FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author=%d";
    return $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql,$authorID));
}
```

Comment: this works : `$sql = "SELECT SUM(comment_count) AS total FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_author=%d"; return $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql,$id));`, prepare function had changes in WP 3.5.

Comment: @maiorano84 how do I then display this?

Comment: @Greenhoe You echo it in whatever template you're using.

Comment: @maiorano84 Just go it working after your edit, thank you very much

Comment: @Greenhoe anytime. Didn't realize until you commented that there was the syntax error.

Comment: @maiorano84 Would you by chance be able to take a look at one of my pages, I was using this locally and everything was working great by then I published it live and I'm getting errors which you can see at http://hearthstoneplayers.com/contributors/

Comment: @maiorano84 the warning that I"m receiving from that is 
Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()

Comment: @Greenhoe Revo's first comment should handle that. I'll update this example with more current code.